# In Watson Discovery, limiting "return"ed fields to aggregation values

Tags: watson, watson-discovery

For the Discovery REST api, the argument/parameter "return" controls which fields are returned.

So if I pass these arguments to the API

```
  {
              "query": named_sector,
              "count": "10",
              "filter": filter_dates,
              "aggregation" : "term(docSentiment.type,count:3)"
    }
    my_query = discovery.query(my_disc_environment_id, my_disc_collection_id, qopts)
    print(json.dumps(my_query, indent=2))
```

I get the following:

```
{
    "matching_results": 14779,
    "aggregations": [
        {
            "type": "term",
            "field": "docSentiment.type",
            "count": 3,
            "results": [
                {
                    "key": "positive",
                    "matching_results": 4212
                },
                {
                    "key": "negative",
                    "matching_results": 3259
                },
                {
                    "key": "neutral",
                    "matching_results": 152
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "6389715fe7e7f711e0bc09d4f1236639",
            "score": 1.3689895,
            "yyyymm": "201704",
            "url": "https://seekingalpha.com/article/4060446-valuation-dashboard-consumer-discretionary-update",
            "enrichedTitle": null,
            "host": "seekingalpha.com",
            "text": "Valuation Dashboard: Consumer Discretionary - Update\n\nSummary\n\nValuation metrics in Consumer Discretionary.\n\nEvolution since last month.\n\nA list of stocks loo ....
```

and thousands of more lines.  How do I restrict the output to the aggregations section?  Is this an issue of me better handling the JSON structure that is returned?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you change the count argument to 0, the returned JSON will only contain the aggregations.

Also, if you're using the Discovery web tooling, you can enter 0 for the "Number of results to return (Count)" field.

More details and an example can be found here: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/discovery/using.html#building-aggregations